# Why is my image repositioning when I resize my screen?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create this effect - picture 1. But this is my current result - picture 2. Looks fine, **but it moves when screen resizes**, look at picture 3.
[image]

I understand that I need to use z-index, which I have, but it is not working as I plan. Currently the element will move a lot when I resize the screen - picture 3 (for example iPhone 8):
[image]

I have tried changing the position attribute and other things, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong. This is the code: 
HTML:

```
              <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div id="showcase__two__element__two">
                    <div class="h-100 row">
                        <div class="h-50 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 showcase-two-groupone">
                            <img src="img/flour.png" class="img-fluid img-flour" alt="Flour image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="h-50 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 showcase-two-groupone">
                            <img src="img/egg.png" class="img-fluid img-egg" alt="Eggs image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="h-50 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 showcase-two-grouptwo">
                            <img src="img/cake.png" class="img-fluid img-cake" alt="Cake image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="h-50 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-6 showcase-two-grouptwo">
                            <img src="img/cakestraw.png" class="img-fluid img-cakestraw" alt="Cake and strawberry image">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 rounded showcase-two-vektor">
                            <span id="showcase-two-vektortext">Tastes so good!</span>
                            <img src="img/vektor.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Tastes so good !">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #showcase__two__element__two {
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 92%;
}

.showcase-two-groupone{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.showcase-two-grouptwo{
    padding: 10px;
}

.img-flour {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    outline: 4px solid white;
    outline-offset: -10px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.img-egg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    outline: 4px solid white;
    outline-offset: -10px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.img-cake {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    outline: 4px solid white;
    outline-offset: -10px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.img-cakestraw {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    outline: 4px solid white;
    outline-offset: -10px;
    z-index: 0;
}

.showcase-two-vektor{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    padding-top: 150px;

}

#showcase-two-vektortext{
    font-family: 'Alegreya', serif;
    color: #c9b176;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

If you want to see the full code, you can here (without the pictures and bootstrap): https://jsfiddle.net/prozik/btvch7c6/

I am using HTML5, CSS3 and Bootstrap 4.

Comment: 1. You can use snippet which provided by stackoverflow
2. You can create div ( for example ) block and give to div "position: absolute; top: calc(50% - height of your rounded picture );"

Comment: This has nothing to do with z-index - your z-index is fine as your middle thing appears above your grid - that's all z-index controls, the stacking context.  You need to set your positioning correctly, by the looks you can use top and left 50% with translate of -50%.  Also what is the point of the fiddle, it adds nothing to this question as you haven't included any bootstrap stylings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can streamline your code a bit by removing superfluous grid declarations (ex. `col-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6` is the same as just declaring `col-6`).

```css
.img-collage {
  position: relative;
}
  
.img-cake {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
  
#img-circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: 25%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#img-circle .img-fluid {
  border-radius: 900px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container img-collage">
  <div class="w-50 h-50 text-center" id="img-circle">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300/000000/" class="img-fluid">
  </div>
  
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="h-50 col-6 mb-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/" class="img-fluid img-cake"></div>
    <div class="h-50 col-6 mb-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/" class="img-fluid img-cake"></div>
    <div class="h-50 col-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/" class="img-fluid img-cake"></div>
    <div class="h-50 col-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200/" class="img-fluid img-cake"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to play with z-index. Try something like this:

```
.showcase-two-vektor {
  ...
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

### Example:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  height: 140px;
  background: blue;
  width: calc(50% - 22px);
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.toast {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: rgba(255,255,0,.4);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="toast">Tastes so good!</div>
</div>
```